# custom variable not added in custom model in my module

Tags: email

I need to add a custom variable with my module in `Mage_Core_Email_Template_Filter` for to use in transactional email. I have tried:
config.xml

```
    <core> 
        <rewrite>
            <email_template_fitler>Mage_Core_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_fitler>
        </rewrite>
        </core>
```

Filter.php

```
<?php
class ITEP_Incomm_Model_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Email_Template_Filter
{
    //variavel para obter código de validação
    public function codeValidationDirective($construction) {
        $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]); 
        return print_r('1142111e2e1we321123211');
        } 
}
```

and using with `{{codeValidation}}`, `{{customVar code=codeValidation}}` but in preview of template the result is the text {{codeValidation}} and not the real value.
Why i need to modify? thanks in advance. My cache is off, and clear.

Comment: I think you are working at the wrong place. You don't need to create a Directive for that matter. In which transactional e-mails do you need to include that variable (customer registration, order,...)? You might be interested in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397373

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved settting the variables in file email.php where is send and catch and shows in real email sended, like this:
USE in template mail: `{{var NAMEVAR}}`, and the email.php:

```
<?php

// How to send.
if (!isset($_GET['email'])) {
    echo 'usage: ITEP_email1.php?email=your-email-address@domain.com';
    die;
}

// Send mail, the Magento way:
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$template_id = 'Name_Template';
$SomeVar1 = "ABC";
$Customvar2= "Skype";

// Loads the template exception
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);

$vars = array("some var" => $SomeVar1 , "custom var is" => $Customvar2);
$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($vars);
echo Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId);

// Set sender information:
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(
        Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email', $storeId));
$emailTemplate->setSenderName(
        Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name', $storeId));
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('template customized email'); //subject for email
// Send the mail:
$output = $emailTemplate->send($_GET['email'], null, $vars);
var_dump($output);
```